# c++ how to define object member of another type without a default constructor

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am pretty new to c++, and trying to write simple boost::asio server wrapper class, and having some troubles with it. Following this example http://thisthread.blogspot.ru/2011/02/minimal-asio-tcp-server.html, and trying to put asio objects inside an object of my class like this:

```
tcpserver.h:

class tcpserver {
public:
    tcpserver(unsigned short port  = 9999);
    ~tcpserver();

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
};

tcpserver.cpp:

#include "tcpserver.h"

tcpserver::tcpserver(unsigned short port){
    endpoint = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v6(), port);
    acceptor = boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(io_service, endpoint);
}
```

And compiler throws following error:
`/Users/rusik/huyorg/lib/tcpserver/tcpserver.cpp:3:12: error: constructor for 'tcpserver' must explicitly initialize the member 'acceptor' which does not have a default
      constructor
tcpserver::tcpserver(unsigned short port){`

How i should do this correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Use the member initializer list of the `tcpserver` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Use it in initialization:

```
tcpserver::tcpserver(unsigned short port) :
    endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v6(), port),
    acceptor(io_service, endpoint)
}
```

Since when you do it your way, the members are temporarely default constructed (which is missing for acceptor) . 
Here they're directly constructed with the correct parameters